# Wrong image alt text on Winter Bash 2015

Tags: bug, images, winter-bash-2015, alt-text

I had just a network issue while loading the main page on my mobile and I was greeted with a Winter Bash 2013 text. I had to double check the url, it seems that the alt text is broken.

[image: winter bash 2013 or 2015?]

Comment: Ehm, sure "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced." This was an issue 5 years ago. Why was this closed *now*?

Answer (score 9):

Yup, busted!

> [image]

Comment: Btw, logo.png produces WB2014 logo :)